# How to Logo Centering on Responsive Webpage

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have made a responsive webpage which has a logo in center position. I could do it using the css such as `logo {width: 615px; margin: 0 auto}` which works well in firefox and opera browser. But it doesn’t work well in chrome browser. It moves slightly left in chrome browser. I want that the logo always display in center position (Desktop and Mobile) on firefox, opera and chrome. How could I fix it? For your kind information, there has some contents in right side of this webpage.

Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211935016/mobile_responsive/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the overflow: hidden which you don't really need for the logo. That should solve the issue.

```
.fix{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Teknotica, thank you for your answer. It works well. I have just another issue. When I reduce my browser the logo moved down. But I want it in the same position always. How could I fix it? Keep well.

Comment: Hi @Teknotica, I like to inform you that it just happen on Chrome browser. You could visit the link again and see the difference. Thanks.